# Importing matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have anaconda and Python 3.6.3 on Mac OS 10.13. I am in the process of learning Python and wanted import matplotlib. However, I keep getting a ModuleNotFoundError when I try to run the program from Chapter 2 of "Doing Math with Python".

Any ideas on how to overcome this hurdle?

Comment: Try using `pip install matplotlib` and then try importing it. Tell me if it works or not. Also are you using only one user in your Mac? Modules need to be installed in that specific user who wants to use it.

Comment: It that for the terminal?

Comment: Yes, in your terminal. You need to have pip. If you don't have pip, go and google how to install it. And go https://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html for how to install matplotlib with pip.

Comment: It says requirement already satisfied:
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.1 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File <path>, line 4, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Comment: As your problem environment dependent, I need more info. Try this, `import sys` `print("\n".join(sys.path))`. This will print a path. Check whether matplotlib is indeed on one of the listed paths (usually site-packages). Also tell me the output of `where python` and `where pip`. Add these to your question as it may be useful to many more people.

Comment: What do I put for sys.path?

Comment: I did not understand, please explain. With sys.path, I want to know the PATH variable of your MAC environment.

Comment: Does this also go in the terminal?

Comment: `import sys` and `print("\n".join(sys.path))` are python commands. The rest two are terminal commands.

Comment: I'm not sure I am doing this right and apologies as I am a beginner. Here is what I have:
print("\n".join( /Users/danielgaichas/anaconda3/python.app))

Answer (score 0):

With anaconda, the installation of matplotlib can be done with `conda`; on the command line, in terminal, type:

```
conda install matplotlib
```

Comment: I did that and it says it is already installed. When I run the program for a simple plot, what should the import command read in Python (IDLE)?