# Error when importing matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I am new to python and am just getting started. I have a Jupyter Notebook from my university and have to plot something using matplotlib. All I find on the web is this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

but when I try that, it tells me

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-e0e1492b7973> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Any help and further tips are very welcome.

Comment: have you installed matplotlib?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361469/importing-matplotlib-in-python possibly dublicate

Answer (score 0):

matplotlib has to be installed

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

since you have the jupyter tag, installing it with the Anaconda Prompt is an option

```
conda install matplotlib
```